# Model too small in Orthographic view

Tags: xna, c#, windows-phone-8

This must be super-basic, but I don't know where the problem is, since I just started with 3D-Programming.

Why is my model "ballTest" so small on the screen?

```
private Model _model;
private Matrix view, proj;

//Initialize()
_model = Content.Load<Model>("ball test");
view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, 10), new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Vector3.Up);
proj = Matrix.CreateOrthographic(800, 480, 0.1f, 30.0f);

//Draw
_model.Draw(Matrix.Identity, view, proj);
```

Comment: Maybe because you created it that small, and in the 3D editor you move the camera in so very close that now you're used to how big it looked in there, but in reality it's not that big?

Comment: It also looks like your zFarPlane is a little bit low, isn't the camera to far away from the object that it only renders part of it? Otherwise, increase zFarPlane and or check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the scale of the model, depending on the size of your model you might have to increase or decrease it in size.

```
float scale = 1f; // No scaling, 0.5f = half size, 2f = double the size
Vector3 Rotation = Vector3.Zero; // No rotation
Vector3 Position = Vector3.Zero; // Default position = 0,0,0

Matrix world = Matrix.CreateScale(scale) *
               Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(Rotation.X)) *
               Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(Rotation.Y)) *
               Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(Rotation.Z)) *
               Matrix.CreateTranslation(Position);
```

then

```
_model.Draw(world, view, projection);
```